# ASA ISP limit of ISP Speed

Tags: cisco-asa, network, isp

I've got configured ASA with two ISP.
First is main ISP and second for backup.

Is possible to set on conf of ASA if the speed of main ISP will be at low bandwith, ASA will active a backup ISP?

Comment: you can use sla configuration on the ASA to monitor reachability of the some resource via main ISP and reroute traffic to second one if something wrong. But, of course it is not about bandwidth itself. Actually, your task is strange, because you should know which bandwidth you have from each ISP  BEFORE to connect to them both

Comment: I can think of a creative way to do this, but not a built-in method.  If you have SNMP monitoring set up in your environment, you could theoretically use that in conjunction with a task trigger, so when your monitoring solution sees an interface usage above a specified threshold, it will issue a command to the ASA to adjust the routes.  There are kinks that would have to be accounted for, but it's doable.

Comment: @JesseP. thanks for that idea. I will do that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The ASA has no ability to test bandwidth/throughput of a giving interface.

Comment: Actually, it knows the bandwidth which is the speed of the interface (how fast the interface serializes the frames). The bandwidth is fixed, but it is the throughput that can vary, and it will be something less than the bandwidth because of protocol overhead.